# some elements processed more than once, some not at all

Tags: java, multithreading, list

I have a fairly straightforward task: I have a list of strings each of which is processed and a score is produced. The string and its score then get added to a map:

```
public class My1Thread 
{
    final private static List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5");

    private static HashMap<String,Double> result = null;

    private Double computeResult(String id)
    {
        Double res = 0.0;
        // do stuff to compute result
        return res;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        result = new HashMap<String,Double>();

        for (String id: ids)
        {
            result.put(id,computeResult(id));
        }

    }

}
```

Since scores of any two strings are independent of each other, this seems to be a perfect case to use multithreading. However, I am getting unexpected results, which is probably a typical result for a multithreading newbie.

Here's a m/t version of the above:

```
public class MyMultiThread 
{
    final private static int nWorkers = 3;  // number of threads

    final private static List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5");

    private static int curIndex = 0;    // indexing pointing to position in ids currently being processed

    private static HashMap<String,Double> result = null;

    public static class Worker implements Runnable {

        private int id;

        public Worker(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        synchronized void setCounter(final int counter)
        {
            curIndex = counter;
        }

        synchronized int getCounter()
        {
            return curIndex;
        }

        synchronized void addToResult(final String id, final Double score)
        {
            result.put(id,score);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try {
                while (true)
                {

                    int index = getCounter();
                    if (index >= ids.size())
                    {
                        // exit thread 
                        return;
                    }

                    String id = ids.get(index);
                    setCounter(index+1);
                    System.out.print(String.format("Thread %d: processing %s from pos %d\n", id, id, curIndex-1));

                    Double score = ...  // compute score here

                    addToResult(id,score);
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        result = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Pair<Document,Double>>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nWorkers; i++) {
            Thread worker = new Thread(new MyMultiThread.Worker(i));
            worker.start();
        }
    }

}
```

According to the output produced by `System.out.print`, this code appears to be processing some elements of `ids` more than once while not processing others at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please include the output and the expected output.

Comment: while calling `getCounter()` though it's synchronized and before calling `setCounter()` another thread could read same value, so same string will be processed twice, as a start if i were you, i would make method `getCounter()` to increase and return counter, so next thread will get updated index, now setCounter() might get fixed automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while(true) loop inside the thread starts at the index specified in the constructor, and then increment it by one, and then the loop starts again. So thread 0 does index 0, then index 1, etc.. Thread 1 does index 1, then index 2, etc... So index 2 will be done 3 times.

I would use a synchronized linked list for ids, and have each thread take and remove the first element of the list, until the list is empty. Use LinkedList.removeFirst().

Also the result hash map also needs to be synchronized, since multiple threads may write to it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the map is being modified concurrently in multiple threads, so some updates are getting lost.

You declared the methods that modify the map as synchronized, but note that they are synchronized on multiple worker objects: not on a single object, which would provide the locking you are after.

I'd recommend using ConcurrentHashMap and getting rid of all the synchronized declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your synchronization is too narrow - for example, this bit here:

```
int index = getCounter();
if (index >= ids.size())
{
    // exit thread 
    return;
}

String id = ids.get(index);
setCounter(index+1);
```

What happens if thread A reads the counter, thread B reads the counter, then thread A updates the counter?

```
A: int index = getCounter(); // returns 3
B: int index = getCounter(); // returns 3
...
A: setCounter(index + 1); // sets it to 4
B: setCounter(index + 1); // Uh-oh, sets it to 4 as well, we lost an update!
```

In this case, when you read a variable, then write to it based on the value you read, both the read and the write need to be within the same synchronization block. Declaring `getCounter` and `setCounter` as *synchronized* is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Java 8 Stream API :

```
Map<String, Double> map = ids.parallelStream().collect(Collectors.toConcurrentMap(id -> id, id -> computeScore(id)));

...

Double computeScore(String id) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(100);
}
```

[Here](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/)'s a nice tutorial.